# IE7 ignores colgroup?

Tags: html, css

trying to set these two columns to have 50% width each but the colgroup is ignored in IE7, can anyone suggest an approach to solve this issue?

```
 <table id="briefEquationBuilder" class="fullWidthTable">
        <colgroup>
          <col span="1" align="left" style="width:50%">
          <col span="1" style="background-color:yellow">
        </colgroup>
```

[image]

Comment: Im only trying to fix a bug, not trying to get buried in more work.

Comment: If there's inadequate browser support, as @Riskbreaker indicates, then there are only two options: (1) Change the HTML (to something that is supported). (2) Don't attempt to fully support IE7.

Comment: The `colgroup` markup as such has no effect, so how can you infer that it is ignored? You should explain what you expect and how this fails, and you should disclose all the relevant CSS code – prefetably, include a complete, self-contained document that demonstrates the issue and explain how it can be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it up like this:

```
<table id="briefEquationBuilder" class="fullWidthTable">
  <colgroup class="yours">
    <col/><col/>
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">copy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But........Why not use **td and add classes**?

colgroup has little support base on this:

http://marc.baffl.co.uk/bugs